# Smoke calculation with mq2 sensor

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, avr, codevision

How to calculate the amount of smoke output from the mq2 sensor?

Comment: Those type of cheap sensors are really only going to reliably tell you if there's smoke or not. Each one has a relatively large variation, without calibration and known amounts of smoke for an individual sensor I don't think you can really do it.

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you?

Answer (score 2):

This is an SnO2 combustible gas (and CO) sensor, not a smoke sensor.

Refer to the (typical) "Sensitivity Characteristics" curve in the sensor datasheet. Ask your supplier for a link to the datasheet if you can't find it.

The typical sensor resistance is given relative to the resistance in a calibration gas such as 1000ppm hydrogen or 1800ppm iso-butane. If you can't immerse each sensor individually in the calibration gas to calibrate it, it's fairly pointless. There is also substantial variation with temperature and humidity.

The unit-to-unit variation in absolute resistance terms under calibration conditions can be about an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

"Smoke" detectors are usually just sensors that detect byproducts of combustion i.e. Carbon Monoxide (CO) (or perhaps unspent LPG gas).

What you need to do is calibrate your sensor to the gas that you want to detect (lets say Carbon Monoxide). You expose the sensor to a known consentration of that gas (i.e 1ppm) and note down the voltage outputted by the sensor (i.e 1v). Now you know whenever 1ppm of CO gas interacts with the sensor, 1v will be detected on the output.

You could connect the output of the sensor to a microcontroller, and use an ADC to detect when the sensor output shows 1v. Then use this information to trigger an alarm.

As said above, 1ppm may equal 1v on sensor A, but may equal 0.7v on sensor B. Unfortunately this is the way sensors work. Each sensor must be calibrated individually.